# Sharp drop in FPS while recording

Tags: video, framerate, hardware

I've recorded a few Minecraft videos using bandicam before without this problem, but yesterday I went to record it was all going good until out of nowhere my FPS went from like 60-100 to 0-2 for like half a second.

I thought it might be because of me changing my screen resolution from 1360 x 1024@60hz to 1440 x 900@75hz. So I switched it back it didn't change anything I tried recording using ultra high 60fps settings again it records fine then out of no where fps goes to 0 usually I have music playing over the in-game audio I turned that off. I even tried the low-end settings and I still got FPS lag although it was smaller it was still there. I switched the drive that it outputs on also to no avail. I don't have a bad setup its pretty new and shouldn't have any problems running this:

- Dell Optiplex 780
- Windows 7 Pro 64-Bit
- Intel Core 2 Duo@3.00Ghz
- 8 GB Samsung PCI-8500F(533Mhz) RAM
- ATI Radeon HD 4670 PCI-Express x16 graphics card 1GB memory
- 1 TB Western Digital HDD
- 320 GB Samsung HM321HI HDD

Also when I playback these recordings they skip sometimes and they speed up almost like I'm watching them at increased speeds. If need be I'll upload one of them so you can see what I'm talking about.

[This is a video that I recorded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEmcS-31snQ) like 2 weeks ago so you know my computer is capable of capturing, I also use the default settings in bandicam (Free Version).

Answer (score 2):

Most screen capture applications are pulling video from the video card down to main memory to compress it and write it to disk. Most video games are uploading textures and geometry to the video card to display it to you. It's possible to get into a situation where more memory is needed on the card to run the game and record the video than you have available. That's usually when you see frames dropping. Depending on the game, it might happen when more characters or scenery is visible (such as when viewing a scene from high up, and it's all in frame). The memory on the card is limited, and the ability to move data around in the computer is also limited. It sounds like you're hitting those limits.

Comment: Also i dont know if this makes a difference but Catalyist  says that my graphics card is using 4798MB of memory (hypermemory)

Comment: Making it faster won't help, but getting more VRAM would. I don't know if the 4670 can have more than 1GB installed, though. If you are using 4798MB of VRAM, that's nearly 5GB, and it would likely be swapping to main memory. I don't know what "hypermemory" means, though, so I'm not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: Hyper memory i believe but could be wrong is the graphics card using the the Motherboards Main Ram as its own although the card only has 1 gig of ram it can use another 4 from the computer as its own (which is impressive for a card as old as this one) and seeing that im usually only using 4-5 gigs of ram that shouldn't be a problem. My initial guess was that it had something to do with my processor like i was reaching its limit but i have 2 cores and pretty much only 1 is getting extreme use while recording.

Comment: Is there an app that can show you CPU and GPU activity? That might tell you where the slowdown is. I've found that when I try to guess what the system is doing, I'm usually wrong!

Comment: Yes, that's what HyperMemory is.  And usually the GPU drivers can show GPU load.  Max HyperMemory is just the upper limit on how much it could use.  It allocates dynamically, rather than just grabbing 4.7GB any time your GPU is doing anything.

Comment: @user1118321: copying frames from the video card back into main memory to feed them to a software encoder doesn't increase VRAM requirements at all.  PCIe is full duplex, but most of the bandwidth requirement is for 3D gaming is from CPU to GPU.  This means the GPU->CPU bandwidth is usually available for getting the displayed frames back for encoding.  IDK what's causing Isaiah's problems, but that's probably not it.